# My WebSocket is not working as expected; the server is implemented in Java and the Client is in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, html, utf-8, websocket

I seem to be having trouble getting a 'proper' connection between my Java server and my JavaScript client. It appears to connect okay, the client sends its header okay, but that's as far as it gets. The `onopen` or `onmessage` functions are never triggered at all.

Here's the code for the Java server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Server {
    static DataOutputStream out;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8112);
            System.out.println("Server Started");
            while(true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("A client connected");
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            //Send a simple-as-can-be handshake encoded with UTF-8
            String handshake = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r" +
            "Upgrade: WebSocket\r" +
            "Connection: Upgrade\r" +
            "WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost\r" +
            "WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8112/\r" +
            "WebSocket-Protocol: sample\r\n\r\n";
            out.write(handshake.getBytes("UTF8"));
            System.out.println("Handshake sent.");

            //Send message 'HI!' encoded with UTF-8
            String message = "HI!";
            out.write(0x00);
            out.write(message.getBytes("UTF8"));
            out.write(0xff);
            System.out.println("Message sent!");

            //Cleanup
            socket.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Everything closed!");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the client:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
      function load() {
        var ssocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8112/");
        socket.onopen = function(e) { alert("opened"); }
        socket.onclose = function(e) { alert("closed"); }
        socket.onmessage = function(e) { alert(e.data); }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
    <body onload="load();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Why won't `onopen` or `onmessage` trigger? I've tried a lot of different things I just can't seem to do it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just noticed a typo in your JS snippet here. "ssocket" should be "socket".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a challenge-response aspect to the protocol that you appear to be missing - the client sends two extra headers and some random data:

```
GET /demo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 12998 5 Y3 1  .P00
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample
Upgrade: WebSocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 4 @1  46546xW%0l 1 5
Origin: http://example.com

^n:ds[4U
```

and the server is expected to derive a MD5 response by:

- extract digits from each key (4146546015, 1299853100)
- divide by number of spaces in key
- serialize keys as 4-byte integers, concatenate with data
- calculate MD5 digest

producing a response like:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://example.com/demo
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample

8jKS'y:G*Co,Wxa-
```

This process is designed to prevent non-WebSocket requests from being handled by WebSocket servers - see section 1.3 of the [WebSocket protocol](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-socket-protocol/) for details.

Comment: This answer made me understand why my WebSocket client (desktop web browser) is not receiving replies from my android SocketServer. But I end up using [java-websocket.org](http://java-websocket.org)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible problems here. HTTP is a request-response protocol. You aren't supposed to send first from the server: you should send a request from the client first. The end of line terminator is defined as \r\n in HTTP. You should be creating a new thread per connection at the server. You should close the output stream, not the socket.

Comment: I'm aware of all those 'possible' errors. Before I came here I tried using '\r\n' instead of '\n'... in fact I tried a lot of things different things, none of them bad a difference. And the Client is sending a handshake, are you saying I should wait until I KNOW it has finished sending it before sending the Server's?

Comment: If you're aware that the line terminator is \r\n you should use it.